# how to use knn for mixed data(nominal and numeric)

Tags: knn, categorical-data

I want to use knn for combination data that includes nominal, numeric attribute(my data is kddcup99). For example, with the hvdm distance measure, can anyone guide me in this area?
Thank you very much for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use knn [in R] for mixed data that includes numerical and nominal attributes, you can use knngow in the dprep package. The way it is used is as follows:

```
library(dprep)
knngow(train,test,k)
```

In knngow it is not necessary to specify the class variable. Since knngow automatically considers the last attribute as the class variable.